# Unable to pass the last few tests in spite of getting the app fulfill all the criteria mentioned in the test suite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I’m working on the [freeCodeCamp's 25+5 clock project](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-development-libraries/front-end-development-libraries-projects/build-a-25--5-clock). Though the app works as expected from the functional pov still I’m unable to pass the remaining 4-5 tests in the test suite.

[Link to the project](https://codepen.io/donjoe21915/pen/VwRPVEb)

Relevant portion of the code for the application:

```
interval;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breakLength: 5,
      sessionLength: 25,
      timer: 1500,
      timerType: "Session",
      timerState: "stopped"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      breakLength: 5,
      sessionLength: 25,
      timer: 1500,
      timerType: "Session",
      timerState: "stopped"
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.timer === 0 && prevState.timerType === "Session") {
      this.setState({
        timer: prevState.breakLength * 60,
        timerType: "Break"
      });
    } else if (prevState.timer === 0 && prevState.timerType === "Break") {
      this.setState({
        timer: prevState.sessionLength * 60,
        timerType: "Session"
      });
    }
  }

  breakDecrement = () => {
    if (this.state.breakLength < 2) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      breakLength: prevState.breakLength - 1
    }));
  };

  breakIncrement = () => {
    if (this.state.breakLength > 59) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      breakLength: prevState.breakLength + 1
    }));
  };

  sessionDecrement = () => {
    if (this.state.sessionLength < 2) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength - 1,
      timer: prevState.timer - 60
    }));
  };

  sessionIncrement = () => {
    if (this.state.sessionLength > 59) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      sessionLength: prevState.sessionLength + 1,
      timer: prevState.timer + 60
    }));
  };

  startTimer = () => {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(
        (prevState) => ({ timer: prevState.timer - 1, timerState: "start" }),
        () => {
          if (this.state.timer === 0) {
            this.buzzer();
            this.stopTimer();
            this.startTimer();
          }
        }
      );
    }, 1000);
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  };


  toggleTimer = () => {
    if (this.state.timerState === "stopped") {
      this.startTimer();
    } else if (this.state.timerState === "start") {
      this.stopTimer();
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      timerState: prevState.timerState === "stopped" ? "start" : "stopped"
    }));
  };

  resetTimer = () => {
    this.stopTimer();
    this.setState({
      breakLength: 5,
      sessionLength: 25,
      timer: 1500,
      timerType: "Session"
    });
    this.audioBeep.pause();
  };

  buzzer = () => {
    if (this.state.timer === 0) {
      this.audioBeep.play();
    }
  };

  clockify = () => {
    const { timer } = this.state;
    if (timer < 0) return "00:00";

    let minutes = Math.floor(timer / 60);
    let seconds = timer - minutes * 60;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
  };
```

Three out of five failed tests(12,14,1,) throw this ‘Timer has not reached 00:00.’, but the timer does reach 00:00 (you can check that out for yourself). Can’t point out which part of the code is causing this problem.

The app fulfills all the required criteria in application but still I can't passs the remaining 4-5 tests in the test suite. I sense a few more amends will do the thing but I've been unable to figure them out so far.
What can I do to pass the remaining tests in the test suite?